# How can I detect whenever a <div> is resized using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I know about  `$(window).resize(function () {.....});` but this only works whenever the window is resized.

I tried attaching this event to a  e.g. `$("#some-div").resize(function () {.....});` and it won't work.

Is there some other method using pure Javascript or jQuery?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GnGQf/1/)

Thanks

Comment: What makes the div to be resized?

Comment: You can create a custom event and trigger it manually if that helps. Here http://jsfiddle.net/GnGQf/2/

Comment: Not sure.. once try `$(document).on('resize', "#some-div", function() {/* code here */});`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/

It might be hard to detect changes just by using events. Adding text to a div may cause a resize but the event triggered does not reveal that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
var divresize = $('#div_name').width();
        $(window).resize(function(){
            if($('#div_name').width() < divresize){
                alert('Your div has been resize')
            }
        })
```

Comment: This only works if the window resizes. The window will not necessarily resize every time my div does.

Comment: Well actually this is what you ask, amplify the resquest to see what you're looking for to achieve with this ;)!!!